# Changing element styles following scrolling from the top

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to apply a different style to the header whenever you scroll down from the top. Basically I want it so that if you are scrolled at the top then apply style 1, but if you are not scrolled at the top then apply style 2.

I have tried using a while and for loop to achieve this but both failed. The jQuery example below did work but for some reason not on this example. However I would rather use JavaScript than jQuery since I am learning JavaScript.

Can someone advise me what should I use for this: a while or if statement? And can someone tell me what I have done wrong with my attempts?

Thanks for any help.

```js
// ATTEMPT 1

var headerWrap = document.getElementById('header-wrap');
var h = headerWrap.scrollTop;

function changeHeaderOpacity() {
    "use strict"; // wtf is this?
    while (h > 0) {
        headerWrap.addClass('scroll-opacity-change');
    }
    headerWrap.removeClass('scroll-opacity-change');
}

// ATTEMPT 2

/*
var headerWrap = $('#header-wrap');
$(window).scroll(function() {
    headerWrap.addClass('scroll-opacity-change');
    if($(this).scrollTop() <= 0) {
        headerWrap.removeClass('scroll-opacity-change');
    }
});
*/
/*

// ATTEMPT 3

var headerWrap = document.getElementById('header-wrap');
var h = headerWrap.scrollTop;

function changeHeaderOpacity() {
    "use strict"; // wtf is this?
    if (h > 0) {
        headerWrap.addClass('scroll-opacity-change');
    } else {
    headerWrap.removeClass('scroll-opacity-change');
    }
}
*/
```

```css
body{
  height:1000px;
}

#header-wrap{
  height:100px;
  width:100%;
  background:#0f0;
}

.scroll-opacity-change{
  background:#f00;
}
```

```html
<div id="header-wrap">

</div>
```

Comment: The jQuery example didn't work for your example because of [css specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity). The background from `#header-wrap` will always wins, even if you add the `.scroll-opacity-change` class to the element.

Answer (score 1):

Well first of all, you need to add listener to detect window scroll.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$(window).scroll(function() {
     //do the header styling using .style
   });
});
```

Now you need to store the scroll log in few variables to figure out you are scrolling down or not, you can the following using this:

```
 var currentScroll = window.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop;
   if (currentScroll > lastScrollTop){
       // You are down scrolling
   } else {
      // You are up scrolling
   }
   previousScroll = currentScroll;
```

Final code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 previousScroll=0 //this means we are starting from top
$(window).scroll(function() {
   var currentScroll = window.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop;
if (currentScroll > previousScroll){
   // Change header style cause you are down scrolling
} else {
  // Do something else? You are up scrolling anyway...
}
previousScroll = currentScroll;
);
});
```

I hope this helps, your comments are welcomed.

Answer (score 0):

Use class instead of id;

> ```
> <div class="header-wrap">
>
> </div>
> ```

and

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
  $('.header-wrap').addClass('scroll-opacity-change');      
  if($(this).scrollTop() <= 0) {
       $('.header-wrap').removeClass('scroll-opacity-change');
  }
});
```